# How do I search a string for keywords found in multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, node.js

So I have some data that looks like this:

```
stringToSearch = 'this string needs to be searched';

labels = ['keys 1-3','keys 4-6','keys 7-9'];

keywords =
    ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
    ['key4', 'key5', 'key6'],
    ['key7', 'key8', 'key9']
];
```

EDIT:
Basically what I'm trying to achieve is, searching the string for any of the keys. Then finding the all of the labels that correspond with the groups that the keys are in.

EDIT: The goal is to pass in the string and get back the labels.

string='this contains key5 and key9';

So it returns, labels 'key 4-6' and 'keys 7-9'

Comment: What do you mean, "tag the string"?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how I'm going to do it yet. Planning to figure that out after I figure out how to find the correct values to tag it with.

Comment: Edited that part out, sorry about that.

Comment: I've added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523663/how-do-i-search-a-string-for-keywords-found-in-multi-dimensional-array/5524262#5524262) for your newest iteration of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, based off your most recent edit:

```
stringToSearch = 'this string needs to be searched';

labelsToApply = {
    myFirstLabel: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
    anotherLabel: ['key4', 'key5', 'key6'],
    lastLabel:    ['key7', 'key8', 'key9', 'key10', 'key11'],
}

function getLabels(str, labels) {
    var appliedLabels = [];
    $.each(labels, function(labelName, keywords) {
        $.each(keywords, function() {
             if(str.search(this) >= 0) {
                 appliedLabels.push(labelName);
                 return false;
             }
        });  
    });
    return appliedLabels;
}

alert(getLabels(stringToSearch, labelsToApply));
```

Comment: I think this will definitely do the trick but I have one question. The labels (as well as the keys) are user submitted strings. What is the best way to inject them into the hash?

Comment: `labelsToApply['newLabel'] = newKeys`?

Comment: Ok, I might not be perfectly clear on how the hash table works. Can I pass in new data just by declaring `labelsToApply['newLabel'] = ['new','Keys']` ? Does `'newLabel'` need to be formatted a particular way, ex. no spaces?

Comment: @float: Yep, that'll work fine. Format of the the label names does not matter at all. If you want to add a key to an existing label, do `labelsToApply['existingLabel'].push('additionalKey')`.

Comment: aweeeeeeesommmmmmmmmmmeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
stringsToSearch = ['this string needs to be searched', '...']

keywords = {
    firstGroup: {
        key1: [],
        key2: [],
        key3: []
    },
    secondGroup: {
        key4: [],
        key5: [],
        key6: []
    },
    thirdGroup: {
        key7: [],
        key8: [],
        key9: []
    }
}

$.each(keywords, function(groupName, keyGroup) {
    $.each(keyGroup, function(key, foundStrings) {
        $.each(stringsToSearch, function() {
            if(this.search(key) >= 0)
                foundStrings.push(this);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The only thing this needs is to keep track of the group name, but that should be pretty simple.  It also would be good to keep track of the position in the searched string where each target is found.

Comment: What do you mean 'keep track of the group name'? It does that by storing strings which match the keys within the group object

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - never mind then :-)  (Still might be nice to keep the index of the substring.)

Comment: Not part of the original question though.

Comment: @Eric well I was just keying off the *original* original question, wherein the author indicated a desire to "tag" the search string somehow. I just figured that knowing the positions would be handy for that; it'd be easy maybe to just push a little object with both the string and the index..  In any case, I upvoted your answer because it's quite elegant.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, sorry if my initial question was unclear, so this will allow me to pass in a string and get back the labels that correspond to its contents? Trying it now, thanks again.

Comment: @float: I think [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523663/how-do-i-search-a-string-for-keywords-found-in-multi-dimensional-array/5524262#5524262) is more suitable

Comment: @float: does the other one do the job? If so, push the little tick mark by it!

Answer (score 1):

In plain old Javascript I would use something like this:

```
var stringToSearch = 'this string needs to be key2 searched key4';

var Keywords = function(keywords, label) {
    this.keywords = keywords;
    this.label = label;
}

var keywords1 = new Keywords(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 'keys 1-3');
var keywords2 = new Keywords(['key4', 'key5', 'key6'], 'keys 4-6');

var keywordsArray = [ keywords1, keywords2 ];

for (var i=0; i <keywordsArray.length; i++) {
    var keywordsEntry = keywordsArray[i];
    for(var j=0; j <keywordsEntry.keywords.length; j++) {
        // here you got the index of the occuring keyword
        if(stringToSearch.indexOf(keywordsEntry.keywords[j]) > 0) {
            // now do sth. with the label
            alert(keywordsEntry.label);
        }
    }
}
```

(Definitely not very well coded, but this is meant to give you a start.)

Answer (score 1):

Or possibly this, since it's unclear what you want:

```
stringsToSearch = ['this string needs to be searched', '...']

keywords = {
    label1: {
        keys: ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
        matches: []
    },
    label2: {
        keys: ['key4', 'key5', 'key6'],
        matches: []
    },
    label3: {
        keys: ['key7', 'key8', 'key9', 'key10', 'key11'],
        matches: []
    }
}

$.each(keywords, function(labelName, label) {
    $.each(stringsToSearch, function(_, stringToSearch) {
        $.each(label.keys, function(_, key) {
            if(stringToSearch.search(key) >= 0) {
                label.matches.push(stringToSearch);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```